# Oracle mutiple session for an application

Tags: oracle, session

I have a problem.
Well, I have an VB6 app that connects to an oracle database. Normally it uses just one session to connect to the database, but after running an update query on a table, it opens another one, on wich it runs just one query : `SELECT VALUE
  FROM SYS.NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
 WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET'`
The update query is :

```
UPDATE SYS_PASS set LAST_LOG = SYSDATE where ID = 'xxxx'
```

Any idee why this is happening, or how could i get rid of this extra session ?

Comment: "Any idee why this is happening, or how could i get rid of this extra session ?" ---- this extra-useless-session is the problem.

Comment: You haven't problem with oracle, you have problem with your VB6 app.

Comment: This might be, but I've debugged it step by step, and the second session appears exactly after running that update query with basic ODBC execute command. So, how could it be the apps fault ?

Comment: After update db never start new session so how could it be the db fault?)

Comment: the app executes un update command, in the same way as many other update coomands - wich don't generate any new sessions - therefore i think it's more likely that the session  is created by odbc or oracle. any ideea about what that "select..." query is used for ?

Answer (score 1):

This extra SQL statement must be generated either by

- your own VB6 program, in which case you need to fix it yourself
- "something" in your technology stack (the ODBC driver?), in which case you need to look at replacing all or parts of that technology stack; which may or may not be feasible (but hey, if you really want to get rid of that extra statement...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want know what for your database do select then ask about select (describe how you detected extra select etc), not about app, while people will not understand what problem do you have.

Your second query executes on the opened connection itself and not on any other connection.

You might be seeing other connection because of connection pooling. You can verify that by setting `Pooling = false` in the connection string.